# When i used join in laravel it returns empty array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

when i try to add join it return empty array in laravel

```
$data = DB::table('driver')
    ->join('order_detail','driver.id','=','order_detail.id')
    ->select('driver.*','order_detail.amount')
    ->get();
```

Comment: You can check the generated sql with `toSql()` method, and request your DB with this.
Can you add table representation ?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct column names? The convention is that `order_detail.id` is the identifier for the row and therefore not a foreign key. By convention you'd name your foreign key `order_detail.driver_id` just double check you're joining on the right columns

Comment: yes coulmn name is correct

Comment: Add your migration schema please

Comment: i updated the code may be the error is because of user_id ?

Comment: Did you check the SQL generate ? And data in your table are right ?

Comment: Based on your shared design you need an additional join. One to join driver with user and one to join user with order detail. The driver does not seem to directly link to the order detail

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that the query did not find matching entries in the order_detail table. This can have a lot reasons. Maybe the order_details.id is the wrong field to match with the driver.id? In order_details maybe there is a field like "driver_id".

Comment: in order table there is another coulmn user_id but it's link to different table

Comment: so what should i do?